# PHP curl to get and send static variable to URL

Tags: php

I want to send static values with curl function. Please correct me with right syntax.
values are

```
<input type=hidden name="cke" value="1">
<input type=hidden name="ownerid" value="2">
```

Curl Function:

```
$fields_string = [

                'cke'=> urlencode($POST["1"])
                'ownerid'=> urlencode($POST["6"])
                ]    
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Also, In next step I want to get those values from HTML from and then post through curl function.

Thanks

Comment: First, you will have to use curl with the URL that has the form. Using simple html dom, for example, get the input fields. After correctly building $fields_string, you will be able to use cUrl to send again the filled form. 1 time build field_strings, 2 cUrl Calls.

Comment: I am using the url function but I did not post it on this forum.
But is it the right way to post static values with in curl function

Comment: So what is your question exactly  You would like to pick up the value of some form and use those value to send through Curl?

Comment: Yes I want to get some values from HTML form and send through CURL.
Also same time I want to send constant values too..